# loading data from 2 column in csv file to rows in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, import-from-csv

I have 1 dataset in csv file which contains 2 columns. They are similar attributes (This dataset is in 0 NF). Now I have created new schema in mySQL where I have assigned only one column for that attribute. My problem is I want to import the old data from csv file to new schema. I know we can use LOAD DATA INFILE command to import the data but is there any way I can load data from 2 column in single column.

Just for better understanding  I have give example schema below.

> orignal table attributes (csv file): 
> Adm_id, SSN, Diagnosis, Medicine1, Medicine2.
>   
>   New table: 
> adm_id, SSN, Diagnosis, Medicine.

**Question: how to load data in medicine column in above schema from old csv file.**

**Explaination :**
This is a different scenario. in skipping column, we do not consider data from that column. But in here, I need to generate 2 seperate rows from 1 row in csv file where each row have sequencially medicine 1 and medicine 2 value in Medicine column of new table

Comment: You can do creative things going in the other direction like [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75297)

Comment: This is a different scenario. in skipping column, we do not consider data from that column. But in here, I need to generate 2 seperate rows from 1 row in csv file where each row have sequencially medicine 1 and medicine 2 value in Medicine column of new table.

Comment: I realize that before you commented...easiest way..LOAD DATA into scratch table (a raw table)...process the data afterward using a Stored procedure, if you only want to do this in SQL..you could do this in other languages as well such as Python, php, etc...We did the preprocessing of our csv files in python before importing in to DB using Load Data...that way they always conformed to table structure we needed regardless of how we received them from clients...

Comment: I had that idea but I was hoping there would be some way where I can do that using LOAD DATA command.

Comment: I upvoted cause you were able to explain and then reiterate your issue more clearly...unfortunately, I do not believe you can manipulate the data in such a way...if you want to keep this in all sql and avoid other languages...load data as is into raw table...then process...

Comment: as far as table structure goes..You can then use the raw table to build a distinct table of `Medicines` each with their own med_id's and then have a separate table of `Diagnosis` with the first 3 columns in your original table...You could then have a bridge table using the `adm_id` and `med_id` to associate the diagnosis with a Medicine...In order to do that properly with the correct FK relationships you would have to process row by row...makes it alot easier to do so if the data is in a Raw table...